# How to get the element that fired the "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

```
<script>
    function clicky(e){
        console.log(e)       //the clicked element
    }
</script>
<span onClick="clicky(this)">Clickable</span>
```

In the script above, the `console.log(e)` will give me the `<span>` that I clicked on.
Is there any way that I could omit the `clicky(`***`this`***`)` and still get the element?
It's because I don't want to put `(this)` all over the document.
Any answer are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo" style="background:blue; width:100px; height:100px">
    <script>
      function clicky(e){
        console.log(e); 
      }
      var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
      foo.onclick = function(e){clicky((e || window.event).target);}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in IE, Opera and Google Chrome. I thought it works in Firefox too but now I see it doesn't.

Comment: I wanted to write some like this but you were faster. Really. :> Anyway, thanks, now all is ok. :)

Comment: That is good enough because I am using it in a Google Chrome extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, not tested though.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
spans.attachEvent('click'.'clicky');

 function clicky(e){
        console.log(e)       //the clicked element
    }
```

or

```
 var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (i in spans)
{
    spans[i].attachEvent('click'.'clicky');
}

     function clicky(e){
            console.log(e)       //the clicked element
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clicky(e, elem){

<span onClick="clicky(event, this)">Clickable</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use Prototype or jQuery or any other library. I would improve your life.